# Getting all email out from iPhone

Tags: email, exchange

I had my email connected to an exchange server. I no longer have access to this server, but all the messages are still stored on my device.

I keep getting messages that I need to reenter my password. I can click cancel, and browse the messages, see the attachments and all.

Is there a way (free/paid) that I can extract all the messages from my device?

I don't want to remove the email account from my accounts, as I do want to keep the messages and attachments.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking too simple, but can't you simply send the mails to another mail account?

Comment: wow, so simple :-) * I used the 'Move' option, and just moved it to a different account. Q: That option has no effect on the old server, correct? as I am disconnected, and can't login.

Comment: I don’t know where exactly you moved the mails to, but if the folder you moved them to is connected/in another account, then deleting the old account should not delete the moved mails.

Comment: thanks. go ahead and make that as an answer, so I can vote. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is to `move` the mails to another account. You can open a certain mail or select multiple mails (hit `edit` in the mail view and select the mails). Then click the folder icon/`move` label and select the folder in a different account to move the mails to.